# Proving denumerable sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**I am not looking for direct answers unless asked for as I am trying to understand the material and improve my discrete mathematics knowledge, thank you.**

> **Proposition:** Sets $A, B$ and $C$ are disjoint denumerable sets. Prove that $A \cup B \cup C$ is also denumerable.

What I know: I know that a denumerable set has the same cardinality (size) of the set of Natural Numbers ($\mathbb N$). I also know that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are disjoint sets meaning they have no common elements so hence: $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$

If we were to list out the set of elements contained in $A \cup B \cup C$ we would have a set (In this example I use $Z$) $Z = \{a_1, b_1, c_1, a_2, b_2, c_2, \ldots \}$.

Is this enough to prove the proposition? We can clearly see this set is infinite as well meaning it must have the same cardinality of the set $\mathbb N$. If not how else can this be re-written in order to show a more concise proof and what other ways could I have re-written the set $Z$ used in the example above.

Comment: "If we were to list out the set of elements contained in A ∪ B ∪ C we would have a set (In this example I use Z) Z = {a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, ... }

Is this enough to prove the proposition? "  Yes,.... if you put a bit more rigor to it.

Comment: What might that look like?

Comment: I don't understand that statement, I do get that we have a function f that maps ℕ to the union of sets A, B and C. but after that I feel quite lost.

Comment: It looks like $1\to a1; 2\to b_1; 3\to c_1; 4\to a_2; 5\to b_2$ etc... can you formalize that?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{N}\to A\cup B\cup C$ as $f(3n-2)=a_n,\:f(3n-1)=b_n,\:f(3n)=c_n$.

Comment: Hint:  If we list $A\cup B \cup C$ as $\{a_1, b_1, c_1, a_2, b_2, c_2, a_3, .....\}$ then what is the $2,576,351$st term in the list?

Comment: That's where I'm struggling because if the 3 sets have no elements in common I cannot just use A_k for some k in the set of integers because it would not follow the disjoint definition.

Comment: Notice you want $z_1=a_1$ and $z_4 = a_2$ and $z_7 = a_3$ so $z_? = a_{2,371}$ and what about $z_{38} = ???$ and $z_?=c_7$ etc.

Comment: Another way of think this is way.  Let $\{z_1, z_2,z_3, z_4, z_5,...... \} = \{z_{a,1}, z_{b,1}, z_{c_1}, z_{a,2},...\}$ where $z_{d,n} = d_n$. (for $d = a,b$ or $c$).  So we have an $\iota:\{a,b,c\} \times \mathbb N\to Z$ where $\iota(d,n) = z_{d,n} = d_n$.  All you need to do is figure some $f:\mathbb N \to \{a,b,c\} \times \mathbb N$ where  $f(n) = (a, k)$.  This *REALLY* shouldn't be that hard. and $f(1) = (a,1)$ and $f(2) = (b,1)$ and $f(3) = (c,1)$ and $f(4) = (a,2)$ and so on...  Hint: how frequently do the a,b,c repeat.  How many times must a,b,c repeat for $n$ to go to $n+1$?

Comment: " I cannot just use A_k for some k "  Why not?  $a_1 \to 1$ and $a_2\to 4$ and $a_3\to 7$ and $a_4\to 10$ and $a_5 \to 13$ and ......

Comment: Well I understand the pattern and I get that a, b and c must all repeat once in order for it to go to n + 1 (a1, b1, c1, then starts a2 etc...) However I do not understand how to formalize it because we cant just say a_g, b_r and c_p where g, r, and p are elements of the set of Integers. If they are all supposed to have different elements that wouldent work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we were to list out the set of elements contained in A ∪ B ∪ C we would have a set (In this example I use Z) Z = {a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, ... }

And that's the key.

But you need rigor.

$A$ is denumerable.  Meaning there is a bijection $\phi_a:\mathbb N\to A$ so that $\phi_a(i) = a_i$ so we can list $A$ as $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3....\}$.

Likewise as $B$ and $C$ are denumerable there are similar bijections $\phi_b: \mathbb N\to B$ and  $\phi_c: \mathbb N\to C$ so that $B = \{\phi_b(1), \phi_b(2), ....\} = \{b_1, b_2,...\}$ and $C = \{\phi_c(1), \phi_c(2), ....\} = \{c_1, c_2,...\}$

So *FORMALLY* define a bijection $\psi: \mathbb N \to A\cup B\cup C=Z$  where $\psi (i) = x_i = .... $ some specific element of $Z=A\cup B \cup C$.

Now bear in mind $\psi(1) = a_1=x_1$ and $\psi(2) = b_1 = x_2$ and $\psi(3) = c_1 = x_3$ and $\psi(4) = a_2 = x_4$.

Can you *formally* define $\psi$?  And once you define $\psi$ can you prove it is a bijections?  If so, that is *all* you need to do.

Comment: I guess I cant formally define ψ , I understand everything up to that point but like most infinite sets were it goes to something subscript n where n is an element of the set of integers implying it goes up until some number. Here it doesnt look like I can define the set that way.

Comment: Of course you can.  Numbers are just numbers and if yo can list them you can list them.

Comment: well shoot I guess I had it all along I just didnt believe in it, I should be able to take it from there by proving its cardinality must be equal to that of an infinite set knowing that the three sets that made this new set were all denumerable sets. And based off of its cardinality it must be a bijection to the set of integers.

Comment: Can you come up with a formula that an will send $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9......, 59,60,61, .....$ to $a_1, b_1,c_1,a_2,b_2,c_2, a_3,b_3,c_3,.....b_{20},c_{20}, a_{21},.....$ ?

Comment: If I could write it in java, absolutly. However, just in math logic I always feel stumped. I simply cannot figure this formula out.